# Matplotlib Image as Background

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

Is it possible to put an Image-file as the background of a plot?

Or is it somehow possible to manually define a plot to look like this:

[image: plot]

I'm pretty new to matplotlib, so could anyone explain me how I can solve my problem?

**What I've done so far**: 
I've created a heatmap array and used the "gray" colormap for the heatmap generation. But this simply looks awful, since the squares do not really represent the smooth lines of the picture.

Comment: This looks a lot like a [`stackplot`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stackplot_demo.html) to me.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you very much